# Split chef resource in multiple files

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, require

I have a fairly long chef resource and would like to split its actions into multiple files, so I would end up with a file resource_main.rb, resource_action_configure.rb, resource_action_load.rb and so forth. Is something like this achievable in Chef?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Ruby doesn't offer that as a feature. That said, a single resource being that long is almost certainly a code smell, can you show what kind of code this is?

Comment: Can't share any code here yet, but what it is is a ressource to install and configure Kubernetes on a multi os basis. In this ressource I have various action, e.g. install, configure (for general configuration), configure_master (for master configuration), configure_node (for node configuration). I guess I could just create sub-ressources for the seperate tasks. Or would you rather recomment recipes for such a thing?